# Mongodb 2.6.10 count() aggregate()

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregate, distinct

In a collection, I need to find groups that have more than 3 members. Show the name of the group and the number of members. Limit the number of results to 4.

The structure is with `{_id, Group_Name, Members:{First_Name, Second_Name, Age}}`

I used aggregate and count in the same structure (using limit too), but the result wasn`t as I expected.

How can I do that? I don't need the age for nothing.

Thanks!
Example:

```
    db.User_groups.find()
    {"_id":ObjectId("654765754575a7"),"Group_Name":"Group_AAA","Members":
    [{"_id":ObjectId("654646646554b8"),"First_Name":"John","Second_Name":
    "Potoshin","Age":34},{"_id":ObjectId("654765117575a8"),"First_Name":
    "Manfred","Second_Name":"Erassy","Age":40},{"id":
    ObjectId("656776432655t5"),"First_Name":"Dieter","Second_Name":
    "Koll","Age":45}],{"_id":ObjectId("654765333575a3"),"Group_Name":
    "Group_BBB","Members":[{"_id":ObjectId("654646222554b2"),
    "First_Name":"Jane","Second_Name":"Pilas","Age":43},
    {"_id":ObjectId("111765117575a1"),"First_Name":
    "Konrad","Second_Name":"Samir","Age":50}]}
```

Comment: Post your sample collection please and are you using mongodb version 2.6?

Comment: Yes, I use 2.6.10 because the virtual machine where I work...

Comment: where is your sample collection? I couldn't see it... Or kindly improve formatting

Comment: I put the example above, in the main paragraph.

Comment: please improve formatting...

Comment: I'm new with this, I don't know what do you need. Thank you as well.

Comment: I want your sample collection... You have posted it but Please improve its formatting

Comment: Please upgrade your MongoDB. MongoDB 2.6 was released in March 2014, it has reached it's end-of-life on October 2016. See [MongoDB Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?#community) to get the current stable version.

Comment: Ashish: I think you asked me this: '{_id, Group_Name, Members:{_id,First_Name, Second_Name, Age}}'

Comment: Wan: Yes, I know, but this version is in one virtual machine at work, and I can't upgrade...